# PHP comment system without SQL

Tags: php, comments

I would like to append comments to an html file. Usually this is done with an append and the newest comments are added to the bottom. Is there a way to have them add to the top instead? Here is the line of code used:

```
$handle = fopen ("comments.html","a");
```

Was told that the "a" is for append. What are other codes? Is there one for add to top?

Comment: Just for information doing this thing is a little unpractical. If you're doing it for learning and fun, Thats OK. But don't do this thing with a real website..

Comment: Everyone can append some un wanted scripts to your site and exploit your users and even the website.

Comment: You can read the manual to find out how to insert into location file you are concerned with.  Voting to close this question as as it stands the title and context has nothing to do with the actual problem, making this question of little value for future readers. That is not to mention that this approach is totally ill-conceived.  If you have a site with any reasonable amount of traffic you are going to have to develop an file read/write contention mechanism as well as deal with the SIGNIFICANT security issue this would present as mentioned by @MiroMarkarian

Comment: what do you have against data bases?

Comment: How about reading http://php.net/fopen ?

Answer (score 3):

Writing to a file is a bit like building houses on a street. It's reasonably easy to walk down to the end of the street and start building a new house. However, it's significantly more difficult to "insert" a new house at the start - you have to pick up and move every other house one section down. Not only that, but everybody's address changes too.

By using `"a"` to append to the existing file, you're building a new house at the end of the street. To insert at the start, you will have to do something like:

1. Open a new file
2. Write your comment to the new file
3. Copy the entire contents of the old file to the end of the new file
4. Close the new file
5. Move the new file on top of the old one, replacing it

Comment: That's a nice analogy.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.2.6 and newer, there is a code to "open the file for writing ... [with] file pointer is positioned on the beginning of the file" - `'c'`.

**However**, it won't just let you write to the beginning of the file.  You have to handle reading all of the existing data and then rewriting it back to the file afterwards - a very inefficient process.

Instead, consider using some kind of structured data format: JSON, XML, CSV, etc.  PHP can read and write many of these formats natively so your comment creation script will write to the bottom with a timestamp and your comment viewing script will read the file and sort the entries by the timestamps on each one.